# Send POST data with FBML on Facebook

Tags: ajax, facebook, post, fbml

I'm new at this, and I can't seem to find the documentation that explains this. But I want to create a Facebook page, where you can send POST data to an external server, preferably with AJAX.

Can someone please point me in the right direction, as I'm stumbling blind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StaticFBML](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=4949752878)